# salt-stack : Using multiple grain files

Tags: python, saltstack

How can I use multiple grain files and organise them in directories :

```
# pwd
/etc/salt
```

This is just an example:

```
etc
└── salt
    └── minion
          ├── minion
          ├── grains_1
          ├── app_name
              └── grains_2
```

Or I am obliged to keep all in `minion` and `grains` file ?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I looked into the [code](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/5879e259a12e7b8336c33100acc243e57fe09ac1/salt/loader.py#L1148) and it looks like the grain loader does not recurse through directories. You *can* supply a `grains_dir` option in your minion config as an extra place to look for grains which may get you what you're looking for.

**Grain loading**

SaltStack grains use the following precedence scheme for loading grains.

- Core grains (this is stuff like the `os` grain where SaltStack derives info from the system itself).
- Custom grains in `/etc/salt/grains` (YAML file you could add custome grains to).
- Custom grains in `/etc/salt/minion` (the minion config file).
- Custom grain modules in _grains directory, synced to minions.

**Dynamic grains (EC2 example)**

You could use something to dynamically set the grains for a minion, a good example of this is the [ec2_tags grains module](https://github.com/saltstack/salt-contrib/blob/master/grains/ec2_tags.py) which basically makes a grain based on EC2 tags assigned to the instance.